# Xcode won't run pre-push hook; does run other hooks; `xcrun git push` works

Tags: xcode, git, macos, githooks

It seems that Xcode won't run a pre-push hook. It happily runs a pre-commit hook, and surprisingly, `xcrun git push` runs the pre-push hook no problem.

I would've thought choosing "Push..." from the "Source Control" menu equivalent to `xcrun git push`! What is happening and can I work around it?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately, my solution was “use SourceTree”...

Answer (score 0):

Started working with pre-commit hooks on XCode, seems that even this is not completely supported.

If I have any 'echo' statement in pre-commit file for a successful commit, then XCode shows below pop-up:
[Successful-commit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPOSS.png)

Now, if I try to commit the changes again, I find that those are already committed.

So, we started using SourceTree for such situations.